# How can I delete the awful debugging 'Loading'?

Tags: javascript, cordova, steroids

Good evening!
I'm writing an application on the mobile platform 'Steroids'. I don't know why, but on each screen of my app the awful debugging 'Loading'. I can't understand, where is it added, it is absent in html DOM (if to check it in google chrome). I also tried to turn off some scripts which are included by he default, but anyway, I could find the reason. Please, share your ideas. The list of scripts, which are added:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&subset=latin,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/ionic/css/ionic.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/stylesheets/application.css" />

<script src="/javascripts/onerror.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/console.log.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="/components/steroids-js/steroids.js"></script> 



<script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: probably un-related, but change `<script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>` to `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`